# Why was god angry with Moses concerning the waters of Meribah-Kadesh

Tags: numbers

The reason for God’s anger with Moses was that God told Moses to speak to the rock to bring forth water to the children of Israel.When Moses struck the rock twice it angered God because the rock that he struck was Christ Jesus . Whenever the Bible speaks of the rock it is referring to Christ

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for this question.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  This question need two things - a Bible reference and some clarity as to what you are asking - the question implies that there are never any literal rocks in the Bible.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why was God angry with Moses concerning the waters of Meribah-Kadesh?

The account in Numbers 20:1-13 describes Jehovah God providing the nation of Israel water to drink while wandering in the wilderness.

The reason for God's anger is stated in verse 12:

> Jehovah later said to Moses and Aaron: “**Because you did not show faith in me and sanctify me** before the eyes of the people of Israel, you will not bring this congregation into the land that I will give them.” (NWT) [bold text mine]

And again at verse 24:

> “Aaron will be gathered to his people. He will not enter the land that I will give to the Israelites, because **you both rebelled against my order** regarding the waters of Meribah. (NWT) [bold text mine]

The article ["A Judge Who Is Firm for What Is Right"](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2009647#h=8) in the Watchtower of Sept. 1, 2009 gives three reasons for God's judgement:

> First, God had not directed Moses to speak to the people, let alone adjudge them rebels. Second, Moses and Aaron failed to glorify God. “You did not . . . sanctify me,” God said. (Verse 12) By saying “*we* shall bring out water,” Moses spoke as if he and Aaron​—not God—​were the providers of miraculous water. Third, the sentence was consistent with past judgments. God had denied the earlier generation of rebels entrance into Canaan, so he did the same with Moses and Aaron. (Numbers 14:22, 23) Fourth, Moses and Aaron were Israel’s leaders. Those with much responsibility have greater accountability to God.​—Luke 12:48.

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever the Bible speaks of the rock it is referring to Christ

Often it is true but not all the time.

Sometimes, a rock is just a physical rock as in Judges 21:13

> Then the whole assembly sent an offer of peace to the Benjamites at the **rock of Rimmon**.

Sometimes, it is used as a negative metaphor as in Jeremiah 5:3

> New American Standard Bible
> O LORD, do not Your eyes look for truth? You have smitten them, But they did not weaken; You have consumed them, But they refused to take correction. They have made their faces harder than **rock**; They have **refused to repent**.